# Passing variable to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, selector

I know there are tonnes of answers to this question and all the answers are the same. I want to pass a variable to a selector. For example

```
var item = 'size_{{$item->size}}';
$("input[name="+item+"]").change(function () {
     console.log('got it');
});
```

Let's say

```
{{$item->size}} == M // So the var item ='size_M'
```

This far the code is doing OK. There is no problem in item variable. But in the selector instead of getting `size_M` it's getting the item string itself.

[image]

Comment: You may have to further delimit the attribute value in quotes as follows: `$("input[name='"+item+"']")`.  This is because your value contains non-alphanumerics (an underscore).

Comment: @ne1410s I've tried that too but the same result

Comment: @ne1410s Can you provide the docs for the same ? Cause official docs never mentioned that

Comment: You can check if there are any matching elements using something like: `alert($('input[name="size_M"]').length)`.  This should simplify your issue and help work out which bit is failing..

Comment: @ANS I have experienced it in the past. I always assumed it was due to the same functionality that occurs in pure CSS.  Eg: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: actually i have to make this dynamic there may be lots of sizes like size_M,size_xxl, size_S and so on

Comment: @ne1410s  https://jsfiddle.net/mLfu79mw/1/ hmm. This Worked

Comment: @MutasimFuad Look at startsWith jquery attribute selector

Comment: Just [tried it](https://jsfiddle.net/vfx6xeLj/) works fine *(just F12 to inspect, view the output in the console when changing the text field)*.

Comment: @ANS Hot dang.  Apparently underscores are ok!  Thanks.  Spaces and other characters though remain to be problematic:  https://jsfiddle.net/mLfu79mw/2/

Comment: @ne1410s yeah exactly :D given some weird characters like dollars and stars then you are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

> actually i have to make this dynamic there may be lots of sizes like size_M,size_xxl, size_S and so on

in that case all you need is

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$( "input[name^='size_']" ).change(function () {
     console.log('got it');
});
```

Comment: They don't need quotes *per se*; only where there's a non alphanumeric character.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mLfu79mw/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are correct. Just checked it. #ne1410s Without quotes also alphanumeric and _ working fine. Only when there are special chars, it fails